# Redirect generates “Headers already sent” errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I’ve instantiated my plugin with a shortcode which does a redirect when it's insert in an article :

```
add_shortcode('redirect', 'handle_shortcode');
```

My shortcode just does a simply thing :

```
$URL=$atts['url'];
wp_redirect($URL);
exit();
```

The problem is when i go to the article where i put the shortcode, i have Headers already sent errors.

How to solve this please ?

Thanks

Comment: You can not redirect inside a shortcode. Check this. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101498/redirect-function-inside-a-shortcode

Comment: Okay thanks, and if i use  add_action('template_redirect', 'templateRedirect');
in my shortcode function ? Thanks